# recursive function using jquery each variable value not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I've HTML in following format:

```
<div class="propBasic containerForReordering">
    <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_msgSection" class="sortable ui-sortable">
        <li itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">WZ_VS_Test_Top
            <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top" class="sortable ui-sortable">
                <li itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.First" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">WZ_VS_Test_Top.First
                    <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.First" class="sortable ui-sortable">
                        <li itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.1" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.1
                            <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.1" class="sortable ui-sortable">
                                <li itemid="" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">{{Drop Here}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.2" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.2
                            <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.2" class="sortable ui-sortable">
                                <li itemid="" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">{{Drop Here}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second
                    <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second" class="sortable ui-sortable">
                        <li itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.1" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.1
                            <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.1" class="sortable ui-sortable">
                                <li itemid="" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">{{Drop Here}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.2" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.2
                    <ul itemid="WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.2" class="sortable ui-sortable">
                        <li itemid="" class="liSortable ui-sortable-handle">{{Drop Here}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I'm running a javascript recursive loop to get a ||| separates string of itemid---parentid---order like following:

```
var getNewOrderForItemAndDescendents = function(selector) {
    var sNewOrder = "";
    var nOrder = 1;

    $(selector).find('>ul.sortable').each(function(index, obj) {           
        sNewOrder += "|||" + $(this).attr('itemid') + "---" + ($(this).parents('ul.sortable:first').length > 0 ? $(this).parents('ul.sortable:first').attr('itemid') : 'NULL')
                + "---" + nOrder++;

        $(this).find('> li').each(function() {
            sNewOrder += getNewOrderForItemAndDescendents($(this));
        });
    });

    return sNewOrder;
}
```

And calling it like

```
var result = getNewOrderForItemAndDescendents($('.containerForReordering'));
```

**ERRPR**
Its returning result like (notice last number 1 before every separator |||):

```
|||WZ_VS_Test_msgSection---NULL---1|||
    WZ_VS_Test_Top---WZ_VS_Test_msgSection---1|||
        WZ_VS_Test_Top.First---WZ_VS_Test_Top---1|||
            WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.1---WZ_VS_Test_Top.First---1|||
            WZ_VS_Test_Top.First.2---WZ_VS_Test_Top.First---1|||
        WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second---WZ_VS_Test_Top---1|||
            WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.1---WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second---1|||
            WZ_VS_Test_Top.Second.2---WZ_VS_Test_Top---1
```

So basically while it would honor the local copy sNewOrder (in recursive context) of function but nOrder variable is not incrementing from jquery each loop and it always stays at 1.

What am I doing wrong??

PS: I tried using index of each(), it always comes as zero even on second element!!! Very weird issue indeed.

PS2: Did a minor change in JS, now no longer supplying order to function call, it was redundant any ways. At every level number should start with 1 but for siblings it would be 2, 3, 4...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured out the issue. My HTML structure is such that each item UL is inside individual LI so there never is any sibling ULs and hence each never runs twice

Updated code:

```
var getNewOrderForItemAndDescendents = function(selector) {
    var sNewOrder = "";
    var nOrder = 1;

    $(selector).find('>li').each(function(index, obj) {
        if ($(this).attr('itemid')) {
            sNewOrder += "|||" + $(this).attr('itemid') + "---" + ($(this).parents('li:first').length > 0 ? $(this).parents('li:first').attr('itemid') : $(this).parents('ul:first').attr('itemid'))
                + "---" + nOrder;

            nOrder = nOrder + 1;

            $(this).find('> ul').each(function() {
                sNewOrder += getNewOrderForItemAndDescendents($(this));
            });
        }
    });

    return sNewOrder;
}
```